# Declare syntax in mysql

Tags: mysql

Please I always have an error when running this query in mysql bench 5.2
"SQL Syntax error near Declare @QuestionnaireID int;................"

```
Begin 
  DECLARE @QuestionnaireID int;
  INSERT INTO dbo.Questionnaire VALUES('Questionnaire 1');
  SET @QuestionnaireID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
  INSERT INTO dbo.QuestionnaireQuestion VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 1, 'This is the first quetion');
  INSERT INTO dbo.QuestionnaireQuestion VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 2, 'This is the second quetion'); 
  INSERT INTO dbo.QuestionnaireQuestion VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 3, 'This is the third quetion');
  DECLARE @QuestionnaireResponseID int;
  INSERT INTO dbo.QuestionnaireResponse VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 1, GETDATE()); 
  SET @QuestionnaireResponseID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 
  INSERT INTO dbo.QuestionnaireAnswer VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 1, 1, 'This is answer to first quetion'); 
  INSERT INTO dbo.QuestionnaireAnswer VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 1, 2, 'This is answer to second quetion');
  INSERT INTO dbo.QuestionnaireAnswer VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 1, 3, 'This is answer to third quetion');

End
```

Answer (score 2):

User-defined variables in MySQL do not need to be declared.

Also, MySQL doesn't have a `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function. What you are looking for is `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Likewise, MySQL does not have a `GETDATE()` function, use `NOW()` instead.

Also, you should be explicitly enumerating the columns you are inserting into for each INSERT statement. For example, since the Questionnaire table clearly has an auto-increment pk you need to enumerate the column you are inserting into or else the insert will fail.

Here is your SQL re-written to resolve the first 3 issues:

```
INSERT INTO test.Questionnaire VALUES('Questionnaire 1'); 
SET @QuestionnaireID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO test.QuestionnaireQuestion VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 1, 'This is the first quetion'); 
INSERT INTO test.QuestionnaireQuestion VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 2, 'This is the second quetion'); 
INSERT INTO test.QuestionnaireQuestion VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 3, 'This is the third quetion'); 

INSERT INTO test.QuestionnaireResponse VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 1, NOW()); 
SET @QuestionnaireResponseID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO test.QuestionnaireAnswer VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 1, 1, 'This is answer to first quetion'); 
INSERT INTO test.QuestionnaireAnswer VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 1, 2, 'This is answer to second quetion'); 
INSERT INTO test.QuestionnaireAnswer VALUES(@QuestionnaireID, 1, 3, 'This is answer to third quetion');
```